# Physics of particles at absolute zero

Tags: energy, particle-physics, black-holes, atomic-physics

At absolute zero, my understanding is that there is no energy in the system, therefore, zero movement. (Disregard it's impossible to reach absolute zero). For right now assume we have hydrogen at absolute zero and we want to interact with the substance without adding energy and we want to manipulate the items of hydrogen and turn it into helium lets say and then add energy back to the substance.

so my question is at absolute zero,

can I interact in any way without adding energy to the system?

And, if I could can I theoretically re-arrange atoms into different substances? Or how about packing them into a super small space and creating a zero kelvin mini blackhole but since it has no energy it doesn't implode on itself due to Hawking radiation.

(this is obviously extremely theoretical and could never happen but I'm super curious thanks.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At absolute zero, my understanding is that there is no energy in the
>   system

That would be true in a classical analysis.  But taking quantum effects into account, a positive [zero-point energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) remains even at absolute zero.

> can I theoretically re-arrange atoms into different substances?

Theoretically, yes.  Some methods might add thermal energy, but you could cool it off again afterward if so.

> Or how about packing them into a super small space and creating a zero kelvin mini blackhole but since it has no energy it doesn't implode on itself due to Hawking radiation.

Such an object might (initially) have a very minimal amount of thermal/kinetic energy, but the act of compressing it would increase the energy.

Even if the thermal energy released by the collapse wasn't a problem, the mass of the material you are assembling is itself another form of energy (just one that isn't available to us in everyday life).  Because of that, there must be a positive amount of energy/mass inside the black hole.  So there is a source for the Hawking radiation even in this situation.